# Wordpress - Update Database - $wpdb->prepare

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I do have a weird problem inside my custom wordpress script. I want to update my database and I used this line of code to do it:

```
$update1 = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_avg_rate SET avg='$raty' WHERE user_id= '$user->ID'"));
```

Problem was now, that my page loaded about 20 seconds so I started debbuging and I found out that $wpdb->prepare needs a second parameter. I tried this code and right now it is working:

```
$update1 = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_avg_rate SET avg='$raty' WHERE user_id= %d'", $user->ID));
```

Problem is now, that in my opinion there is a ' (at the end by %d) closed but never opened so I tried these codes:

```
$update1 = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_avg_rate SET avg='$raty' WHERE user_id= '%d'", $user->ID));

$update1 = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_avg_rate SET avg='$raty' WHERE user_id= %d", $user->ID));
```

As soon as I am using those codes the site load is again more than 20 seconds. Can someone help me and tell me what the correct syntax for the database update is?

Comment: Is wp_avg_rate a very large table?  How many rows does it have?  Is the user_id column indexed?

Comment: No it is not a very large table and again I am just wondering about the ' which should not be there but it is working so I am wondering what the correct code will be

Comment: Try  `...SET avg=%s WHERE user_id= %d",$raty, $user->ID));`

Comment: Are you basing whether it "works" or doesn't work solely on the speed?  Or, are you verifying that each one is doing the update it's supposed to do?  Log your SQL string: `$sql = $wpdb->prepare(...); someLogMethod($sql)` or echo it out if you have a local instance...then run the actual SQL against your DB...then you can see if it's a valid query taking 20 seconds while an invalid query errors out and doesn't do anything to the DB...which would be my assumption based on what you wrote above.

Answer (score 4):

The correct syntax for this SQL query is:

```
$update1 = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_avg_rate SET avg='$raty' WHERE user_id= %d", $user->ID));
```

prepare will replace the %d with a sanitised integer of `$user->ID`

The 20 second delay you are seeing must be a problem with your database, database server, or your connection to it, which we can't troubleshoot given the information provided.

Here are things you can try

- First and foremost make sure that the SQL is getting generated properly.  Check out Debug Bar, and the SAVE_QUERIES option for wp-config
  https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress
- Next Check that you can perform these queries quickly using a MySQL Client.  I would recommend using the mysql command line tool if possible but PHPMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench will do the job too
- Finally if the query is correct and fast when executed in a client, then you might want to check your DNS settings.  I have encountered similar problems caused by the Database Server not being able to resolve the WordPress server's hostname

Please let me know how that goes!